# SQLCMD utility : connection to second instance does not work

Tags: sqlcmd

I have only `SQLCMD` utility installed locally and want connect to MSSQL instance, but it seems the tool cannot parse the instance name
example:

```
sqlcmd -S SERVER\INSTANCE -U sa -P password
```

However, I can use this command from the machine where SQL Server is already installed.

Error message:
Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server : SQL Server Network Interfaces: Error Locating Server/Instance Specified [xFFFFFFFF]..
Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server : Login timeout expired.
Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server : A network-related or instance-specific error has occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. Server is not found or not accessible. Check if instance name is correct and if SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. For more information see SQL Server Books Online..

Answer (score 0):

To use SQLCMD to connect to a remote server instance use the full URI of your server over the network like so;

```
sqlcmd -S FULLSERVERURI\INSTANCE -U sa -P password
```

for example, if you had your server at 'someplace.com', your connection would be

```
sqlcmd -S someplace.com\INSTANCE -U sa -P password
```

The machine/server would need to have port `1433` open. Consider your network security options.

Comment: hi, it does not work for me, i have used FQDN, it really looks as problem with SQLCMD. As said i can connect to SQL Server instance when connecting from machine with SQL Server and SQL Management Studio installed.

Comment: Do you get an error message? If so, please add the error message or a screenshot so as to enable us better understand the situation.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure you enable TCP/IP Protocol. This is different from allowing network connections in the server properties.

This is a MSSQL 2012 example, but I have it tested on MSSQL 2017 Developer (full) and still works the same (and also, fails just the same when disabled)

[image]